# tox does not update dependency in "requires" section

Tags: python, setuptools, tox

I've got the following tox.ini file:

```
[tox]
envlist = py36, ...
requires =
    tox-venv
    setuptools==49.2.1 # latest
    ...

[testenv:py36]
deps = ...
```

Running it seems fine:

```
tox -e py36
py36 installdeps: setuptools==49.2.1, ...
```

Yet *setuptools* has not been installed correctly (and this causes issues in installing py36's deps):

```
 .tox/py36/bin/pip list
 Package    Version
 ---------- -------
 pip        18.1
 setuptools 40.6.2
```

Same diagnosis running the venv itself:

```
source .tox/py36/bin/activate
python -c "import setuptools; print(setuptools.version.__version__)"
python -c "import setuptools; print (setuptools.__file__)"
40.6.2
.tox/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py
```

Even weirder, I am able to update it "manually":

```
.tox/py36/bin/pip install --upgrade setuptools
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/.../setuptools-49.2.1-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: setuptools
  Found existing installation: setuptools 40.6.2
    Uninstalling setuptools-40.6.2:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-40.6.2
Successfully installed setuptools-49.2.1
```

Am I missing something? I am using tox 3.18.1 with Python 3.6.10 on Linux.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK turns out it was the "tox-venv" requirement that was messing things up.